# Add contributors to existing Meteor.js package?

Tags: javascript, meteor, package

I've published a Meteor package, https://atmospherejs.com/linto/fontawesome, and now I want to add some more contributors to it, but I no longer have a local copy of the repo.

How can I add contributors via Atmospherejs.com?

Comment: In the meantime we have an official integration for Font-Awesome at atmospherejs.com/fortawesome/fontawesome. Pretty please deprecate your package in favor of the community-maintained one, which also has a [blessing from the Font-Awesome developers themselves](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/pull/5062).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case 'fontawesome' is an organization, you can go to meteor.com login with your regular username look for the 'organization' 'tab' under your account settings and 'invite' new users based on their meteor developer usernames.

In case 'fontawesome' is only the package name, hence 'linto:fontawesome' you must use the meteor CLI to add another maintainer via meteor admin!

Comment: Could you provide the CLI example too? Thanks!

Comment: `Meteor admin maintainers <package name> --add <username>`. Run `meteor help admin maintainers` for more options.